# My sketch won't show anything when running in processing

Tags: java, processing

I am completely new to processing, and I wanted to test it by creating a simple sketch that draws a rectangle, however, when i run the sketch, a window pops up with nothing on it. I tried filling it, putting an outline on it, and various other things, nothing happened. I don't think it's a problem with the code but a problem with the app itself, and i'm not sure how to fix it. I am using processing 3.5.4 on windows.

Code:

```
class Sketch {
  void setup() {
    size(100, 100);
  }
  
  void draw() {
    rect(50, 50, 25, 25);
  }
}
```

Expected Output: A square shows up on screen.

Output: Nothing shows up

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gAQsX0hpAyH_iSbUXkyO87a8NpXscLEL/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit confusing. Are you running this in the Processing editor, or are you trying to run it in a website? You've posted an image, but you posted it as if it was JavaScript. Can you try to be more specific about exactly what you're doing?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp [Processing](https://processing.org/) uses java syntax.

Comment: I was running it in the processing editor, i just used an HTML snippet to show the image because i couldn't upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chiming in with the obvious (don't hurt me if I didn't get your question right):

`draw()` and `setup()` are already of Processing. In fact, those you wrote into a class won't be automatically executed, as Processing will be looking for it's own methods. That's why you get this:

[image: No square here]

Which is, incidentally, exactly the same result as if you ran an empty sketch.

To fix this, just take `draw()` and `setup()` out of the class, and Processing will then find and run them:

```
void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  rect(50, 50, 25, 25);
}
```

[image: Out of the class]

Have fun!